# Replace english digit with persian digit in String except URL's

Tags: java, android, string, textview

I wrote a custom TextView for persian String, this TextView should replace english digit's to persian digit's

```
public class PersianTextView extends TextView {

    public PersianTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public PersianTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public PersianTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @Override
    public void setText(CharSequence text, BufferType type) {
        String t = text.toString();
        t = t.replaceAll("0", "۰");
        t = t.replaceAll("1", "۱");
        t = t.replaceAll("2", "۲");
        t = t.replaceAll("3", "۳");
        t = t.replaceAll("4", "۴");
        t = t.replaceAll("5", "۵");
        t = t.replaceAll("6", "۶");
        t = t.replaceAll("7", "۷");
        t = t.replaceAll("8", "۸");
        t = t.replaceAll("9", "۹");
        super.setText((CharSequence)t, type);
    }
}
```

this View work correctly, but if i set a text from HTML, the links which contain english digits will not show as link!
what is the easiest way to solve problem?

Comment: I am not sure what is the problem. Can you give us example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One needs in some form do pattern matching on links.

```
private static final Pattern DIGIT_OR_LINK_PATTERN =
    Pattern.compile("(\\d|https?:[\\w_/+%?=&.]+)");
// Pattern:          (dig|link                 )

private static final Map<String, String> PERSIAN_DIGITS = new HashMap<>();
static {
   PERSIAN_DIGITS.put("0", "۰");
   PERSIAN_DIGITS.put("1", "۱");
   PERSIAN_DIGITS.put("2", "۲");
   PERSIAN_DIGITS.put("3", "۳");
   PERSIAN_DIGITS.put("4", "۴");
   PERSIAN_DIGITS.put("5", "۵");
   PERSIAN_DIGITS.put("6", "۶");
   PERSIAN_DIGITS.put("7", "۷");
   PERSIAN_DIGITS.put("8", "۸");
   PERSIAN_DIGITS.put("9", "۹");
}

public static String persianDigits(String s) {
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    Matcher m = DIGIT_OR_LINK_PATTERN.matcher(s);
    while (m.find()) {
        String t = m.group(1);
        if (t.length() == 1) {
            // Digit.
            t = PERSIAN_DIGITS.get(t);
        }
        m.appendReplacement(sb, t);
    }
    m.appendTail(sb);
    return sb.toString();
}
```

P.S.

Depending on what text, it might be better to only replace digits outside HTML tags, that is between `>` and `<`.

```
private static final Pattern DIGIT_OR_LINK_PATTERN =
    Pattern.compile("(\\d|<[^>]*>)",
        Pattern.DOTALL|Pattern.MULTILINE);
```

Answer (score 1):

try this, haven't check if this works:

```
String t = text.toString();

// separate input by spaces ( URLs don't have spaces )
String [] parts = t.split("\\s+");
t="";

// Attempt to convert each item into an URL.
for( String item : parts ) try {
        URL url = new URL(item);
        t+=item + " ";
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            String temp = item;
            item.replaceAll("0", "۰");
            etc.
            etc.
            t+=item + " ";
        }
super.setText((CharSequence)t, type);
```

Answer (score 1):

### Convert English numbers to Persian numbers method :

```
public String persianNumbers(String englishNumber) {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    String str = englishNumber;
    char[] persianChars = {'\u0660', '\u0661', '\u0662', '\u0663', '\u0664', '\u0665', '\u0666', '\u0667', '\u0668', '\u0669'};

    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        if (Character.isDigit(str.charAt(i))) {
            builder.append(persianChars[(int) (str.charAt(i)) - 48]);
        } else {
            builder.append(str.charAt(i));
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Number in English : " + str);
    System.out.println("Number In Persian : " + builder.toString());

    return builder.toString();

}
```